# Plot problem with xts-object containing different types

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I wanted to to plot (specifically plot.xts) a time-series created with the xts-package. I noticed, that xts-objects containing different types (e.g. Dates, numerics, etc.) are somehow not treated as xts-object by the plot.xts function. I don't have the plotting problem if I only use one type (numerics). What's different between xts-objects containing different types and xts-objects only containing one type?

Here is a small example of what I mean:

```
testDate<-as.Date(c("2014-12-31","2015-01-03","2015-01-04"))
testFrame1<-data.frame(Date=testDate, A=c(1,2,3), B=c(1,3,5))
testXTS1<-as.xts(testFrame1, order.by=testDate)
plot.xts(testXTS1$A)
#Which yields to this error
#Error in plot.xts(testXTS1$A) : 'x' must be a time-series object
```

However

```
class(testXTS1$A)
#states that testXTS1$A is of class "xts" "zoo"
```

Now if I don't include the Date column to the dataframe, specifically the xts, I don't have any problems plotting the data.

```
testDate<-as.Date(c("2014-12-31","2015-01-03","2015-01-04"))
testFrame2<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,3), B=c(1,3,5))
testXTS2<-as.xts(testFrame2, order.by=testDate)
plot.xts(testXTS2$A)
#Plots everything as intended, no error message
```

Another weird thing is that I can't do calculations with **testXTS1** without casting.

```
testXTS1$A+testXTS1$B
#Error in `+.default`(testXTS1$A, testXTS1$B) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

testXTS2$A+testXTS2$B
#works fine again
```

So my question is, what is different between **testXTS1** and **testXTS2**? They both seem to be xts-objetcts, but in some way **testXTS1** isn't?

Sorry if this is a repost, I couldn't find an answer to this question yet.
Thanks in advance!

Greetings
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

testXTS1 is an xts object, but it is filled with characters as the matrix also contains the date column. You can see that all the values are surrounded with quotes (") if you just print testXTS1 (See below). testXTS2 on the other hand is an xts as it is intended with the index being the dates and the matrix is filled with numbers. This is also the reason why your calculations don't work.

You need to exclude the date column from your data.frame when creating an xts object.

```
# printing objects to show difference:
testXTS1
           Date         A   B  
2014-12-31 "2014-12-31" "1" "1"
2015-01-03 "2015-01-03" "2" "3"
2015-01-04 "2015-01-04" "3" "5"

testXTS2
           A B
2014-12-31 1 1
2015-01-03 2 3
2015-01-04 3 5
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So everytime I create a xts-object that contains multiple data types it will automatically change the values to strings?

Comment: @Plsdontjudgeme111, yes that is correct. You have to be careful with that when creating xts objects.

Comment: Do you know how I can check what data type/class a specific value of my xts-matrix has?